# getting undefined while accessing nested json

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking to retrieve `people_id`, `username`, `name` and `people_type` from the following JSON data. Ultimately I have to populate these details in a bootstrap modal table. The following 
is the jQuery code I have been using to retrieve the details :

```
.done(function (data_, textStatus_, jqXHR_) {
 $.each(data_.people_list, function(key, value) {

                    $.each(value.details_list, function(k,v) { 
                              console.log("Inside Loop:"+v.name); 
                              $.each(v.role, function(k1,v1) { 
                              console.log("Inside Another Loop for Role Name:"+v1.people_type); 
                              }); 
                    });
              });  

 })
```

At present I am trying to access only `name` and `people_type` .Here is the output I am getting on my console:

```
 Inside Loop:First Hand Details
 Inside Another Loop for Role Name:undefined
 Inside Loop:First Hand Details
 Inside Another Loop for Role Name:undefined
 Inside Loop:UAB Multiple Myeloma Registry
 Inside Another Loop for Role Name:undefined
 Inside Loop:First Hand Details
 Inside Another Loop for Role Name:undefined
 Inside Loop:First Hand Details
 Inside Another Loop for Role Name:undefined
 Inside Loop:First Hand Details
 Inside Another Loop for Role Name:undefined
```

Why `people_type` is undefined? I read online that one gets `undefined` when that particular thing doesn't exist?

```
{
  "webservice_status" : {
    "status" : "SUCCESS",
    "message" : ""
  },
  "people_list" : [ {
    "people_id" : 001,
    "username" : "pxy123",
    "full_name" : "James Camerion",
    "details_list" : [ {
      "id" : 1234,
      "name" : "First Hand Details",
      "role" : {
        "type_id" : 3042,
        "people_type" : "SuperUser"
      }
    } ]
  }, {
    "people_id" : 002,
    "username" : "gbt123",
    "full_name" : "Tom Cruise",
    "details_list" : [ {
      "id" : 1234,
      "name" : "First Hand Details",
      "role" : {
        "type_id" : 3041,
        "people_type" : "Normal User"
      }
    }, {
      "id" : 5678,
      "name" : "Second Hand Details",
      "role" : {
        "type_id" : 3042,
        "people_type" : "SuperUser"
      }
    } ]
  }, {
    "people_id" : 003,
    "username" : "txt456",
    "full_name" : "Michael Jordon",
    "details_list" : [ {
      "id" : 1234,                                                                                                      
      "name" : "First Hand Details",
      "role" : {
        "type_id" : 3042,
        "people_type" : "SuperUser"
      }
    } ]
  }, {
    "people_id" : 004,
    "username" : "mxn788",
    "full_name" : "Paul Walker",
    "details_list" : [ {
      "id" : 1234,
      "name" : "First Hand Details",
      "role" : {
        "type_id" : 3042,
        "people_type" : "SuperUser"
      }
    } ]
  }, {
    "people_id" : 005,
    "username" : "nhgy234",
    "full_name" : "Brad Pitt",
    "details_list" : [ {
      "id" : 1234,
      "name" : "First Hand Details",
      "role" : {
        "type_id" : 3042,
        "people_type" : "SuperUser"
      }
    } ]
  } ]
}
```

Comment: role is an object not an array, no need to loop over it

Comment: At the same "level" you access `v.name`, you can access `v.role.people_type`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get expected result use below option
No need to loop v, as it is available with .each() and it is a single object and not having multiple objects

```
$.each(test[0].people_list, function(key, value) {

                    $.each(value.details_list, function(k,v) { 

                              console.log("Inside Loop:"+v.name); 

                              console.log("Inside Another Loop for Role Name:"+v.role.people_type); 

                    });
              }); 




var test =[{
  "webservice_status" : {
    "status" : "SUCCESS",
    "message" : ""
  },
  "people_list" : [ {
    "people_id" : 001,
    "username" : "pxy123",
    "full_name" : "James Camerion",
    "details_list" : [ {
      "id" : 1234,
      "name" : "First Hand Details",
      "role" : {
        "type_id" : 3042,
        "people_type" : "SuperUser"
      }
    } ]
  }, {
    "people_id" : 002,
    "username" : "gbt123",
    "full_name" : "Tom Cruise",
    "details_list" : [ {
      "id" : 1234,
      "name" : "First Hand Details",
      "role" : {
        "type_id" : 3041,
        "people_type" : "Normal User"
      }
    }, {
      "id" : 5678,
      "name" : "Second Hand Details",
      "role" : {
        "type_id" : 3042,
        "people_type" : "SuperUser"
      }
    } ]
  }, {
    "people_id" : 003,
    "username" : "txt456",
    "full_name" : "Michael Jordon",
    "details_list" : [ {
      "id" : 1234,                                                                                                      
      "name" : "First Hand Details",
      "role" : {
        "type_id" : 3042,
        "people_type" : "SuperUser"
      }
    } ]
  }, {
    "people_id" : 004,
    "username" : "mxn788",
    "full_name" : "Paul Walker",
    "details_list" : [ {
      "id" : 1234,
      "name" : "First Hand Details",
      "role" : {
        "type_id" : 3042,
        "people_type" : "SuperUser"
      }
    } ]
  }, {
    "people_id" : 005,
    "username" : "nhgy234",
    "full_name" : "Brad Pitt",
    "details_list" : [ {
      "id" : 1234,
      "name" : "First Hand Details",
      "role" : {
        "type_id" : 3042,
        "people_type" : "SuperUser"
      }
    } ]
  } ]
}];


$.each(test[0].people_list, function(key, value) {

                    $.each(value.details_list, function(k,v) { 

                              console.log("Inside Loop:"+v.name); 

                              console.log("Inside Another Loop for Role Name:"+v.role.people_type); 

                    });
              });
```

Codepen:
http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/BzrEVN

output:

```
Inside Loop:First Hand Details
Inside Another Loop for Role Name:SuperUser
Inside Loop:First Hand Details
Inside Another Loop for Role Name:Normal User
Inside Loop:Second Hand Details
Inside Another Loop for Role Name:SuperUser
Inside Loop:First Hand Details
 Inside Another Loop for Role Name:SuperUser
 Inside Loop:First Hand Details
Inside Another Loop for Role Name:SuperUser
Inside Loop:First Hand Details
Inside Another Loop for Role Name:SuperUser
```